# Ionic: Error while running application in my android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am learning ionic. and i was trying running my new app in my android device using `ionic cordova run android` but, I got following error.

> /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/sevenbits/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json'
>
> You don't have access to this file.

```
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
at Configstore.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
at new Configstore (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:45)
at new Insight (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:38:34)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:26:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

**Note**: I have already set permissions 777 to the folder.

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you did not have your development environment set up properly. 
Check the link below on how to deploy your app to a Device.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/

I hope this help.